# Simplest use of transpose given a vector and a matrix

Tags: matrix

Suppose that I have:

```
x = {1, 1}/Norm[{1, 1}];
A = {{1, 2}, {2, 1}};
```

What is the simplest way of calculating $x^T A\ x$?

And are there symbols on any of the palettes for the Transform?

Comment: `x.A.Transpose[{x}]` ?

Comment: I'll go one simpler: `x.A.x`. That result is superior since it gives a scalar, like I presume you expect, but putting `x` in a list to `Transpose` gives you a one element list as a result.

Comment: `x` is a vector, not a matrix, thus transpose makes no sense.  `x.A.x` gives you what you need.  Mathematica supports arbitrary dimensional tensors.  Compare with MATLAB, which simply doesn't have vectors, only $1\times n$ or $n\times 1$ *matrices* which are sometimes called "row vectors" or "column vectors", even though they're really matrices, i.e. rank-2 tensors.  Mathematica works with fully general tensors of *any* rank instead of just matrices, thus there's no need to bother with row or column matrices.  Plain vectors (rank-1 tensors) will do.

Comment: I think belisarius and @rcollyer are both right - it just depends on what you want to do with the result. Most likely, you want a pure scalar and therefore need just what rcollyer stated.

Comment: Thinking again, you probably want what @rcollyer posted. I'm leaving my comment up there, though, just in case

Comment: Not that you need it here, but Transpose has a symbol and since you're asking about it: esc-tr-esc after the object you want to transpose, but be beware of its operator precedence.

Comment: @Szabolcs But you can consider a vector as 2x1 matrix for "practical purposes".